# How to prevent the device from connecting to the original AP?

Tags: authentication, wifi, aircrack-ng, deauth-attack

I'm running an Evil Twin attack with airgeddon. Point is that after deauth the account is going, automatically, to get reconnected to the orginal AP and not the fake one.

The aireplay is likes so:

```
aireplay-ng -0 0 -a [BSSID] wlan0 -c [TARGET MAC]
```

Comment: What type of security does the original network use?

Answer (score 0):

DoS is tricky. To answer you, more data is needed... your chipset, that is very important.

I'll quote the well explained text from airgeddon's wiki. It will throw some light to you:

> Not all attacks work against every APs and its clients. Sometimes, clients are taken down only partially, while others remain unaffected even on the same AP. It depends of many factors and variables: Chipset used to perform the attack, type of client (Android, computer, Apple device, etc), Access Point, distance and signal to the target, etc. The signal is of greater significance, which must be powerful enough. If you think it is not working, you should try a different mode of attack: mdk4, aireplay or even mdk3 modifying the configuration options ".airgeddonrc" file. More info about the available options on this [link](https://github.com/v1s1t0r1sh3r3/airgeddon/wiki/Options)

The entire link is here:

https://github.com/v1s1t0r1sh3r3/airgeddon/wiki/FAQ%20&%20Troubleshooting#dos-deauth-is-not-working-what-can-i-do